# Creating multiple files with names matching a pattern from one file

Tags: linux, command-line, csplit

I have a text file such as:

```
>Tolten.WP_096573835.1
MSSPKSLLIRRARIILPNGELMVGDVLTRDRQIVEVAPEIYTPTPTTEIDAAGLTLLPGVIDPQVHFREPGLEHKEDLFTASCACAKGGVTSFLEMPNTRPLTTN
--
>Trivar.WP_011317016.1
MSSPQSLLIRGARILLPNGEFLLGDVLIRDRHIIEVGTEIVNTTPATEIDAKGLTLLPGVIDPQVHFREPGLEHKEDLFTASCACAKGGVTSFLEMPNTRPLTTS
--
>uniSU2.WP_085434158.1
MTQLLIRHAQILLPNGQFLLGDVLTQDGKILEVASEIAATDLSNIIDATGLTLLPGVIDPQVHFREPGLEHKEDLFTATCACAKGGVTSFLEMPNTRPLTTTQAA
--
>Chlfri.WP_016876644.1
MSETPLLDKVIKNVRVVRPNQHTIEKVDIGIKNGKFAQIAPQISPDQTKEVFDAKNLLGFPGVVDAHMHIGIYQPLAQDAVSESKAAAMGGVTTSLNYIRTGQYY
--
>Noslin.WP_099070767.1
MSEASLLDRVIKNVRVVRPHNDAIELLDLGIKDGKFARIASHISPDTAKEVFDAKNLLGFPGVVDAHMHIGIYQPLDKDAVTESKAAAMGGVTTSLNYIRTGQYY
```

I want to create multiple text files with the content between each and every "--". The text files would be named after the the string starting with ">".

In the end I would have these text files:

```
Tolten.WP_096573835.1
Trivar.WP_011317016.1
uniSU2.WP_085434158.1
Chlfri.WP_016876644.1
Noslin.WP_099070767.1
```

With the following content:

**Tolten.WP_096573835.1** text file:

```
>Tolten.WP_096573835.1
  MSSPKSLLIRRARIILPNGELMVGDVLTRDRQIVEVAPEIYTPTPTTEIDAAGLTLLPGVIDPQVHFREPGLEHKEDLFTASCACAKGGVTSFLEMPNTRPLTTN
```

**Trivar.WP_011317016.1** text file:

```
>Trivar.WP_011317016.1
    MSSPQSLLIRGARILLPNGEFLLGDVLIRDRHIIEVGTEIVNTTPATEIDAKGLTLLPGVIDPQVHFREPGLEHKEDLFTASCACAKGGVTSFLEMPNTRPLTTS
```

**uniSU2.WP_085434158.1**

```
>uniSU2.WP_085434158.1
    MTQLLIRHAQILLPNGQFLLGDVLTQDGKILEVASEIAATDLSNIIDATGLTLLPGVIDPQVHFREPGLEHKEDLFTATCACAKGGVTSFLEMPNTRPLTTTQAA
```

**Chlfri.WP_016876644.1** text file:

```
>Chlfri.WP_016876644.1
    MSETPLLDKVIKNVRVVRPNQHTIEKVDIGIKNGKFAQIAPQISPDQTKEVFDAKNLLGFPGVVDAHMHIGIYQPLAQDAVSESKAAAMGGVTTSLNYIRTGQYY
```

**>Noslin.WP_099070767.1** text file:

```
>Noslin.WP_099070767.1
MSEASLLDRVIKNVRVVRPHNDAIELLDLGIKDGKFARIASHISPDTAKEVFDAKNLLGFPGVVDAHMHIGIYQPLDKDAVTESKAAAMGGVTTSLNYIRTGQYY
```

I know csplit works for this sort of thing:

```
csplit --suppress-matched original_text_file.txt '/^--/' '{*}'
```

But I can't get it to name the files appropriately.

Does anyone know how to help?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid `csplit` can't do that directly, you can only change prefix and suffix of filenames using a "fixed" format. nothing stops you of doing the renaming afterwards using a simple loop, e.g.:

```
$ csplit --suppress-matched original_text_file.txt '/^--$/' '{*}'
129
129
129
129
129
$ for f in xx*; do mv "$f" "`head -n 1 "$f" | cut -c 2-`"; done
$ ls -1
Chlfri.WP_016876644.1
Noslin.WP_099070767.1
original_text_file.txt
Tolten.WP_096573835.1
Trivar.WP_011317016.1
uniSU2.WP_085434158.1
$
```

you can easily combine `csplit` and the loop to get a one-liner:

```
csplit --suppress-matched original_text_file.txt '/^--$/' '{*}' && for f in xx*; do mv "$f" "`head -n 1 "$f" | cut -c 2-`"; done
```